# Selecting multiple headers shifts values along axis 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file which has a bunch of data about tv programmes. I am encountering a problem when trying to read in this data into a pandas dataframe. It currently has two headers, but when I do something like this

```
data = pd.read_excel("Book2.xlsx", skiprows=[0], header=[0,1])
```

the data seems to have shifted by 1 column and the first column becomes the index. So now everything does not have the original reference.

Input data:
[image]

```
            Kids (10-15)                Males (21-30)               Females (21-30)     
Date    Time    Programme   Reach   Total   Percentage      Reach   Total   Percentage      Reach   Total   Percentage
20/07/2019  13:00   Friends 1000    34500   0,028985507     1223    67789   0,018041275     89903   999300  0,089965976
21/07/2019  13:30   Big Bang theory 245 34500   0,007101449     2678    67789   0,039504934     38880   999300  0,038907235
22/07/2019  14:00   Community   255 34500   0,007391304     2909    67789   0,042912567     8937    999300  0,00894326
```

The pandas dataframe when I read it in using the code above:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The cause of irregularities when you read your file is that some columns
are empty and should be skipped.

But unfortunately, if the index on columns is a **MultiIndex**, then you
can not pass *usecols* parameter.

To circumvent this limitation, you have to take such a 3-step approach:

- Read **only** column names (header lines), skipping empty columns
  with *usecols*, calling *ffill*, to "replicate" names in the top level
  and then calling *fillna* to change "initial" *NaN* values in the top row.
- Read **only** data rows, skipping empty columns as before.
- Set column index from *header*.

So the code to read your file should be:

```
header = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', header=None, skiprows=1, nrows=2,
    usecols='A:F,H:J,L:N').ffill(axis=1).fillna('')
data = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', header=None, skiprows=3, usecols='A:F,H:J,L:N')
data.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(header.values)
```